# How to get boolean type return from OrientationEventListener?

Tags: android, orientation

I have a problem to solve in Android Studio, but I'm pretty new in it. I have to create a variable that increments all the time when `onResume()` method is called, but if the orientation is changed the variable must not be incremented.

I wanted to solve this with an if-else statement inside the `onResume()` method (that increments the variable if the `OrientationEventListener` returns false, and doesn't effect the variable if the orientation changed(true)), and with toasts to write out the value of the variable. But, I don't know how to get boolean type return from it, even though I searched for the answer for hours. 
There were similar problems, but I couldn't implement their soultions with success. Here is my code if it helps:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String MY_TAG = "tagged";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void mOrientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(this SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

        }
    };

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int sum = 0;
        int ak = int onOrientationChanged;
        if ( != 0) {
            Log.i(MY_TAG, "onResume");
            tToast("onResume:");
            sum++;
            nToast(sum);
        }else {
            nToast(sum);
        }
    }
    private void tToast(String s) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, s, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
    private void nToast(Integer a) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, a, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could save the last displayed orientation, if it's the same as the current, you increment, and otherwise you do nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrientationEventListener` is used when you need to know the precise orientation of the device's rotation in degrees (from 0 to 359). I assume that you're talking about orientation in the landscape/portrait sense, so `OrientationEventListener` isn't really the right way to solve this.

I think the best thing to do would be to check the orientation in `onCreate()` each time, and compare that with the previous orientation to set a flag `didChangeOrientation` or something like that, and then you could use this flag in your `onResume()` operations.

```
private int orientation;
private boolean didChangeOrientation;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("orientation", orientation);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;        

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        int previousOrientation = savedInstanceState.getInt("orientation");
        didChangeOrientation = (orientation != previousOrientation);
    }
    else {
        didChangeOrientation = false;
    }

    ...
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!didChangeOrientation) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```